# How to get reviews from different sources?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a web service from where I can get reviews from different sources,  for the products which I am selling on my site.

Answer (score 2):

Take a shot at [ViewScore](http://www.viewscore.com/) and [retrevo](http://www.retrevo.com/). Both of which aggregate the ranks and reviews of various sources and shopping sites. The latter slants more toward electronics.

For both sites they will show you snippets of the original reviews with a link to the source site for the complete write-up.